# What is the meaning of outputs_collections in slim.arg_scope?

Tags: tensorflow

Saw this in the alexne.py in slim, could not find the documentation for this. Was wondering what is a collection? I am guessing its a type of container, in this case it would be for output nodes? And was wondering what is the purpose of this, as opposed to using the name of the outputs.

```
    with tf.variable_scope(scope, 'alexnet_v2', [inputs]) as sc:

    end_points_collection = sc.name + '_end_points'
    with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d, slim.fully_connected, slim.max_pool2d],
                        outputs_collections=[end_points_collection]):
        net = slim.conv2d(inputs, 64, [11,11], 4, padding = 'VALID', scope ='conv1')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collections are just containers to group graph nodes which have similar meaning.

Say, any new trainable `Variable` is placed into a collection named trainable_variables and could be accessed using `tf.get_collection('trainable_variables')`.

Similarly, you could pass a collection for outputs of the layer.